# NoCredentialsError : Unable to locate credentials - python module boto3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am running `django` in a `python` virtual environment(`virtualenv`). The `django` website is served by `apache2` from an amazon ec2 instance(ubuntu 16.04). I use `boto3` module to write to amazon s3.

I installed `awscli` and ran `aws configure` and set up my aws access keys correctly. *( I know I configured it correctly, because `$ aws s3 ls` returns the correct lists of my s3 buckets.)*

However, when I try to write some objects to s3 from django application, it fails producing the error as described in the title.

**I recently moved to a new instance and started using python virtual environments. Before that, it used to work fine.** I have read the questions on SO and the docs from aws. Below is the stack trace.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://*******/product/4

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'abc.apps.abcdirectConfig')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/abcdirect/abcdirect/views.py" in view_product
  385.             s3.Bucket('abccms').put_object(Key=s3_file_name, Body=s3_file_data)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py" in do_action
  520.                 response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py" in __call__
  83.         response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py" in _api_call
  253.             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/client.py" in _make_api_call
  530.                 operation_model, request_dict)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py" in make_request
  141.         return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py" in _send_request
  166.         request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py" in create_request
  150.                                      operation_name=operation_model.name)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py" in emit
  227.         return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py" in _emit
  210.             response = handler(**kwargs)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/signers.py" in handler
  90.         return self.sign(operation_name, request)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/signers.py" in sign
  147.             auth.add_auth(request)

File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/auth.py" in add_auth
  679.             raise NoCredentialsError

Exception Type: NoCredentialsError at /product/4
Exception Value: Unable to locate credentials
```

Comment: Check out credentials on `~/.aws/credentials` are set up correctly.

Comment: @juliansalasyes they are correctly set up. And I can connect to s3 from command line and upload/download files. Just not from the django app through boto3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out the reason I was getting the error. I am posting the answer just in case someone else encounters this issue.

**tl;dr : aws config files did not live in apache's home directory**

The django app was running under the user www-data(apache2). When I configured my credentials using `aws configure`, my settings were stored in `.aws/config` file.

### Now this is where the problem was.

The `.aws/configure` file was stored in **my** home directory and not in the home directory of **www-data**(apache2),which is `/var/www` by default. So when the django app called boto3 module, the module was looking for the config file in `/var/www/.aws/config` but my files were in `/home/ubuntu/.aws/config`.

Simply copying the relevant files to `/var/www/` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have already applied your solution and moved both the configuration files to /var/www folder but for me it is still showing the same error. I am using flask + apache to run the application.

Comment: @Ajay make sure the file now lives in /var/www/.aws/config. And male sure apache can read the file. Change the permissions of .aws directory and config file inside it to be readable by others, or change the owner to apache.

Comment: I have made the owner of both the files to ubuntu from root as apache is not a valid user in my ec2 machine. The error remains the same after performing these operations.

Comment: Make sure 'www-data' has read access to the file. Apache runs as 'www-data' user ( cat /etc/passwd lists all users in your system )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145622/discussion-between-ajay-and-bishal-sapkota).